# jQuery custom plugin with click event: Provide options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make my first jQuery-Plugin so please be gentle with me.

The purpose is to make a divs child elements votable. A vote should occur on click.

This is my actual code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.makeVotable = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            // defaults:
            url: "/vote",
        }, options );

       this.bind("click.makeVotable", function (e) {
            var parent = $(this).parent();

            var foreign_type = $(parent).attr('data-vote-foreign-type');
            var foreign_id = $(parent).attr('data-vote-foreign-id');
            var vote_id = $(parent).attr('data-vote-id');
            var vote = $(e.target).attr('data-vote-type');
            var what;

            if($(e.target).is('.voted')) {
                what = 'delete';
            } else if($(parent).children().hasClass('voted')) {
                what = 'update';
            } else {
                what = 'add';
            }

            $.post(
                settings.url,
                { what: what, foreign_type: foreign_type, foreign_id: foreign_id, vote: vote, vote_id: vote_id }
            ).done(function( data ) {

                $(parent).children().removeClass('voted');

                if(what != 'delete') {
                    $(e.target).addClass('voted');
                }

                if(what == 'add') {
                    $(parent).attr('data-vote-id',data.id);
                }

            }).fail(function() {
                /* Heavy error like 500 */
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.votable > i').makeVotable(
    url: "{{URL::to('vote')}}", /* laravel way to get the URL */
);
```

If I delete the "var settings [...]" part and just pass the url without "url:" I can access it with options.url but with this approach I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed something (a pair of `{}` )

```
$('.votable > i').makeVotable(
   { url: "{{URL::to('vote')}}" }
);
```

Comment: Oh my god that's just embarrassing. Works like a charm now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course. I've already voted it up. To make it a correct answer I have to wait 10 minutes ;)

Comment: Okay, Not a problem. :)